# How to emit event to same user which is opened in different tabs or browser in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

i found by creating room it can be executed..but some where something is wrong.

serverside:-

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io   =  require('socket.io')(http);
var users = {};
var rooms = [];


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

 socket.on('Init', function(data){
  if(data in users){

   var roomName = 'room'+ data;
   var index = rooms.indexof(roomName);
   if(rooms.notContain(roomName)){
    rooms.push(roomName);
   var index = rooms.indexof(roomName);
    users[data].join(rooms[index]);
    socket.join(rooms[index]);
   }else{
    socket.join(rooms[index]);
   }
  }else{
   socket.username = data;
   users[socket.username] = socket;
  }

  var indo = rooms.indexof('room'+ data);
  socket.in(rooms[indo]).emit('hai', data);
 });
});

Array.prototype.indexof = function(Obj){
 return this.indexOf(Obj);
}
Array.prototype.notContain = function(Obj){
 for(i in this){
  if(this[i] === Obj) return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Client Side:-

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', { 'forceNew': true});
var userId = '<?php echo $_GET['userId'] ?>';
socket.on('connect', function(){
 socket.emit('Init', userId);
});
socket.on('hai', function(data){
 alert(data);
});
```

Please check this or get me any other solution to solve this issue. I want same user to emit which is opened in different browser or tabs.

Comment: What is wrong with the program? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to send a message to all connections which are the same user. Here is one way to do that:

```
var user_sockets = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket){
 socket.on('Init', function(data){
  if (typeof user_sockets[data] === 'undefined') {
    user_sockets[data] = [];
  }

  user_sockets[data].push(socket);
  for (var i = 0; i < user_sockets[data].length; i++) {
    var s = user_sockets[data][i];
    s.emit('hai', data);
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay….i have some doubts …first i will clarify my requirement first
In the above its possible to emit to all socket which is inside the data array! 
but how can i detect the user? wether the socket is of same user?

Consider A as an user and A has logged into the chat application, and again same A has opened account in another tab or browser, So i have to emit  all events to A and it has to receive in all tabs and browser where A has logged in. and code should also behave for all user (if B has logged in also).

Comment: i found lot of Articles say’s room can rectify the problem of creating multiple connections and socket for single user by inserting all those sockets related to user A to a room and emit event to that room.

Hope you understand the issue. Thanks a lot for the response and i appreciate the helping mentality.
agin thanks in advance for you future assistance to rectify the issue. :)

Comment: What was the issue you had with your solution?